# I'm trying to add a List-Unsubscribe header to my e-mail header using php-mailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I want to show unsubscribe links beside the email headers of email providers like Gmail, yahoo, and outlook.

This is how its called in PHP-mailer:(I have tried by following ways)

1st way:

```
$mail->AddCustomHeader("List-Unsubscribe:<mailto:example@yopmail.com>,<https://myexample.com/unsubscribe.php?identifier=1599&type=s&campaignid=99>");
```

2nd way:

```
$mail->AddCustomHeader("List-Unsubscribe:<mailto:example@yopmail.com?subject=unsubscribe>,<https://myexample.com/unsubscribe.php?identifier=1599&type=s&campaignid=99>");
```

By this code, it sends the header List-Unsubscribe with the email but the unsubscribe link is not showing there. I don't know this is the process or not.

I have DKIM: PASS record.

In the mail raw header of Gmail, outlook, and yahoo it shows, List-Unsubscribe: List-Unsubscribe: mailto:example@yopmail.com?subject=unsubscribe,https://myexample.com/unsubscribe.php?identifier=1599&type=s&campaignid=99. Do we need to do some email server configuration for this to show link in emails header ? I can not find the solution for this.

Comment: While this looks right, whether gmail in particular shows them is quite hit and miss. gmail's spam filtering is terrible, and anything short of utter perfection in your sending history will make them suppress the appearance of that button, which is very unhelpful. You can be absolutely sure of what you're sending by enabling debug output (`SMTPDebug = 2`) when you send.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but I just manage to do this using symfony/mailer and addtextHeader method :

```
$mail->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('List-Unsubscribe', '<mailto:unsubscribe@mydomain.dev?subject=unsubscribe>, <https://www.mydomain.dev/unsubscribe>');
```

Check if it works with :

- https://www.mail-tester.com/

Sources :

- https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html#message-headers
- https://mailtrap.io/blog/list-unsubscribe-header/